# Move textfield up when keyboard covers it up

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am not that familiar with Objective C , and was wondering if there is a solution to this in Swift.

It's a very simple SingleView app that I'm playing with. UIView is inheriting from UIControl.

I don't have a UIScrollView, Can't I just move the whole view up? I believe the keyboard is independent of that.

Comment: This is not a Swift question, but rather a UIKit question. Apple has published a guide on this topic.

Comment: @jtbandes I added the [uikit] tag on Marin's behalf, I think it's still a valid question, even if badly tagged? – I don't, however, know the answer, but good luck finding a solution Marin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Look at "Receiving keyboard notifications".

The code samples in that document are all Obj-C so you'll have to convert it to swift on your own, but as @jtbandes said, it's not a swift question per se.

Answer (score 12):

Apple's recommendation recoded in Swift.

Make sure your controls are on a ScrollView and note the colon in the selector string. I use a variable (activeField) to indicate the active text field.

```
var activeField: UITextField?

@IBAction func editingBegan(sender: UITextField) {
    activeField = sender
}

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardOnScreen:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardOffScreen:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

}

func keyboardOnScreen(notification: NSNotification){
    let info: NSDictionary  = notification.userInfo!
    let kbSize = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue().size
    let contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets  = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize!.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize!.height
    //you may not need to scroll, see if the active field is already visible
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField!.frame.origin) ) {
        let scrollPoint:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField!.frame.origin.y - kbSize!.height)
        scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
    }

}


func keyboardOffScreen(notification: NSNotification){
    let contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source link for Apple's recommendation?

Comment: I used the link from jsd above and then rewrote it in Swift.

Comment: @IBAction func editingBegan(sender: UITextField) {
    activeField = sender
} this part of code doesn't work, rather see my code modified below which works on all devices, just need to copy paste.

Answer (score 7):

I used the code here. Did not need to add scrollview

[Move uitextfield up when keyboard shows](http://www.jogendra.com/2015/01/uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard.html)

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        animateViewMoving(true, moveValue: 100)
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        animateViewMoving(false, moveValue: 100)
}

func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
    var movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.3
    var movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0,  movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just updated ChinLoong answer above to the Swift 3 syntax. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to add comments yet.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 100)
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(up: false, moveValue: 100)
}

func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
    let movementDuration:TimeInterval = 0.3
    let movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0,  dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Comment: You should've specified why and what you've updated